# How to convert built-in method values of dict object to dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

```
dic = {}
dic[3] = [1,2,3]
dic[1] = [4,5,6]
dic[6] = [7,8]
S = np.sum(dic.values, axis=0)
```

`dic` is a dictionary, `{3: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 6: [7, 8]}`. `S` should also be a dictionary, right?

```
print(S)    # <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f36df660b88>
print(type(S))    # <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Is it possible to convert `S` to a dictionary, like `{3: 6, 1: 15, 6: 15}`?

Comment: `dic.values` is a dictionary method. `list(dic.values())` is a list of lists.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with your code is in this line:

```
S = np.sum(dic.values, axis=0)
```

`dic.values` is a function. You have to call it! Nonetheless, the result you get is not what you expect:

```
np.sum(np.array(dic.values()), axis=0)
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
```

This is because `axis=0` means: *sum everything you find in the array i'm giving*.
Which translates to:

```
[4, 5, 6] + [1, 2, 3] + [7, 8] = [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
```

Thus, the best solution you have is using a list comprehension:

```
{k: sum(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: 15, 3: 6, 6: 15}
```

Comment: Actually the result of `np.sum(np.array(dic.values()), axis=0)` is `dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]])`, which is the same with `print(dic.values())`

Comment: Check it again! The result is ```[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]```

Comment: Which version of `numpy` are you using?

Comment: I use numpy `1.16.2`

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {3: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 6: [7, 8]}
S = {k: sum(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Then output is `S = {3: 6, 1: 15, 6: 15}`.

If you use Python 2.x, use `dic.iteritems()` instead of `dic.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
dic = {3: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 6: [7, 8]}
c = {k: sum(dic[k]) for k in dic}
# c = {3: 6, 1: 15, 6: 15}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for sub in the_list:
    for key in sub:
        sub[key] = int(sub[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

a = {3: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6], 6: [7, 8]}

b = {i:sum(a[i]) for i in a}

print(b)